# Преобразовать объект mathplotlib в изображение и возвратить его

Tags: python, graphics

Привет, stack owerflow, тут такая проблема:
Надо сделать так, что бы объект из mathplotlib сразу же сохранялся в изображение(формат неважен).

def matching(image, template):

```
img2 = cv2.imread(image, 0)
img1 = cv2.imread(template, 0)

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[:10], None, flags=2)


plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
```

Результат последних двух методов надо сохранить в изображение. Возвратить желательно тоже. (изображение)

Comment: [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) же ж

Comment: вы можете [использовать `cv2.imshow()` чтобы показать картинку и `cv2.imwrite()` чтобы на диск её записать.](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

Comment: Спасибо! четыре пять